# Creating a basecamp TODO returns a 403 forbidden (restsharp, asp.net mvc, basecamp api)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, restsharp, basecamp

I can get a todo without any problem, but when I POST a todo in basecamp I get 403 forbidden

Here is my code

**CODE**

```
var client = new RestClient()
{
    BaseUrl = "https://basecamp.com/" + accountId + "/api/v1/projects/" + projectId + "/todolists/" + todolistId + "/todos.json"
};

string baseCampClientId = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["bcClientId"];
string baseCampClientSecret = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["bcClientSecret"];
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(todo);
request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "MyApp (my@email.com)");
request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("charset", "utf - 8");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", userInfo.BaseCampToken);
request.AddParameter("client_id", baseCampClientId);
request.AddParameter("client_secret", baseCampClientSecret);
request.AddParameter("access_token", userInfo.BaseCampToken);
request.AddBody(json);
var result = client.Execute(request);
string jsonResult = result.Content;
```

The response is always `403 Forbidden`

The json which I send in the request body is

**JSON**

```
"{\"content\":\"solve this thing\",\"due_at\":\"2014-07-10T00:00:00.0000000\",\"assignee\":{\"id\":\"1111111\",\"type\":\"Person\"}}"
```

and here is the image of the request

[image: Response of The Call]

Please help me to fix this `403 forbidden` issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i tried your code with only changing one thing and it worked for me. my changes were:

1. client.Authenticator = new Auth2AuthorizationRequestHeaderAuthenticator(userInfo.BaseCampToken) for 
   request.AddParameter("access_token", userInfo.BaseCampToken);

also try removing "assignee" from your json data if you have any.

Comment: thank you, that solved it, but why to remove an assignee ? instead of sending access_token in parameter (which basecamp api) does not support I had to send it in the head .. thank you

Comment: @NaveedAhmad I send the Assignee when I create a ToDo and it works fine for me.